# How can I judge whether if form input value is number or not?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to proceed `transaction` when `params[:points]` is not a number. I coded like this.

```
if params[:points] !=~ /^[+-]?\d+$/
  transaction
end
```

However, it proceeds `transaction` even when I input `abcdefh` into `params[:points]`. How can I fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All values received from a form are Strings. Some might look like a numeric value, but they'll remain strings until you explicitly convert them to an integer, which you can do using [String's `to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) method.

You can check to see if the entire value contains digits, which is a good clue that it's truly a number using something like:

```
!!params[:points][/^[+-]?\d+$/]
```

to return true/false if it's a string version of a number.

```
'012345'[/^[+-]?\d+$/]
=> "012345"

!!'012345'[/^[+-]?\d+$/]
=> true

'+012345'[/^[+-]?\d+$/]
=> "+012345"

!!'+012345'[/^[+-]?\d+$/]
=> true

'-+012345'[/^[+-]?\d+$/]
=> nil

!!'-012345'[/^[+-]?\d+$/]
=> true

'0 foo'[/^[+-]?\d+$/]
=> nil

!!'0 foo'[/^[+-]?\d+$/]
=> false
```

Comment: even if I code `if params[:points].to_i !=~ /^[+-]?\d+$/`, it won't work:(

Comment: You can't use a regular expression against an integer. They only work with strings.

Comment: that's weird:( I coded `when !!params[:points][/^\d+$/]` and input `abcdef`. However it won't proceed transaction

Comment: If you input `abcdef`, the test will return false.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `.match`, not `!=~`.

```
unless params[:points].match(/^[+-]?\d+$/)
  #stuff
end
```

Alternatively, I finally figured out that the 'does not match' operator exists, it's just that it's `!~`, not `!=~`. So yeah, taking out that equals sign should also solve your problem.

Comment: Oh. Right. You want it to *not* be a number. Sorry.

Comment: I have some other conditions so I cannot use `unless` can't I use `!`?

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely use `!`. I just like the `unless` syntax - it feels more readable. If you do have other conditions, it makes sense.

Comment: it doesn't seem like working:( I did `!params[:points].match(/^[+-]?\d+$/)` and `abcdef` however it won't proceed transaction:(

Comment: Are you sure the error is in this part of the conditional? Do you perhaps have some missing or misplaced parenthesis? I'm quite confident that `!'abcdef'.match(/^[+-]?\d+$/)` evaluates as true.

Comment: can I take off +- thing? I just want positive integer

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You provided the regular expression, I figured you wanted it that way.

Comment: I wish I could give both you guys best answers. but he answered a little bit earlier so this time I will give him best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are confused by your own logic.

- `params[:points]` is `"abcdefh"`
- → `params[:points] !=~ /^[+-]?\d+$/`
- → `transaction` is executed

On the other hand,

> I'd like to proceed transaction when params[:points] is not a number

That is exactly the case. Nothing is wrong.